# Model Binder - protect from malicious automatic binding

Tags: c#, owasp

Recently i was asked question how to prevent malicious automatic binding attacks because client want to implement OWASP standard on his MVC site. I know that parameter should be validated against range of acceptable values , also found [this](http://ironshay.com/post/Mass-Assignment-Vulnerability-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) etc. but my question is do you know any good practice for this ? To prevent security sensitive fields from those kind of attacks in MVC ?

Any point to the right direction will be good

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `CAPTCHA` is one good practice for form submitting

I know this comes after model binding, but it will prevent automated attacks

I personally use `CAPTCHA` for contact us forms and registration forms

More robust approach, is sending a user a verification link, ex:

If a user wants to register for a service, request his email address, and the `CAPCHA` verification. Then send him a verification link to his address if `CAPTCHA` is verified and address looks valid

When the user clicks on the link that he received, he will be redirected to the page that accepts the rest of the form info that he should fill [after you verify the info in the link that is is valid and you have sent this info actually]

This way you will eliminate the possibility that a user is an automated script.

Please see [this example](https://www.qcb.gov.qa/agenda/Privacy/RequestFeedbackForm?conferenceId=2) that I have recently implemented